# SQLAlchemy RDS IAM login

Tags: sqlalchemy, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

I am trying to connect our `SQLAlchemy` connections with our `RDS Aurora` cluster. The issue is that just before we connect we need to get a auth token via the `boto3`. When we retrieve this password once on application startup we get issues after 30 minutes (since then `SQLAlchemy` starts refreshing the connections but the auth token is not valid anymore). I know there are workarounds using the creator method in the `create_engine` method ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562372/how-to-handle-ever-changing-password-in-sqlalchemypsycopg2)), however this makes the solution database engine specific (for example postgres with psycopg2 driver).

I would like to have a solution that doesn't include a choice of driver and let `SQLAlchemy` do this for me. However, just before the connection of `SQLAlchemy` I want to do this boto call and change the URL. I have tried different approaches, using a plugin or a custom Pool. However all those approaches I tried didn't succeed due to the fact that I couldn't influence the url before connection (with a plugin) or that I couldn't get the url (using a custom pool).

Do you all have an idea how I could fix this issue without the need to bind the code to a specific DBMS driver. Would like to hear from you

Answer (score 1):

The best option I can think of is if you have a way to determine which database you need and use a factory function send as creator for example, if you have an environment variable with that you could do something like this:

```
import os
from functools import partial

def connection_factory(database, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return partial(FACTORIES[database], *args, **kwargs)
    except ImportError as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f'No driver installed for database {database}' from e
    except IndexError as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f'No factory for database {database}')

def postgresql_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    import psycopg2
    return psycopg2.connect(..., *args, **kwargs)

def mysql_factory():
    import MySQLdb
    return MySQLdb.connect(..., *args, **kwarg)

FACTORIES = {'postgres': postgresql_factory, 'mysql': mysql_factory}

engine = create_engine(..., creator=creator_factory(os.environ['DATABASE_ENGINE'])
```